# MacBook Pro 3,1 (late 2007, g84m), Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Nvidia won't boot

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, mac, macbook-pro

Let me be clear - this is only a problem when using the Nvidia drivers. I can boot the machine with nouveau, however the machine won't sleep properly and I have no 3D acceleration.

Any time I install (`apt-get`) any version of Nvidia drivers (current, 304, 331, -updates variants), the machine won't boot to a login window. It will usually stop with a black screen or a black screen with a cursor. I have `nomodeset` in grub and have removed `quiet splash`, which is the only way I can get it to boot at all, no matter which drivers I'm using (Nvidia or nouveau).

The card is a g84m (GeForce 8600m GT). I have been working on trying to solve this for about a week on my own so I'm finally here. I can't seem to find anybody that has successfully posted or written about booting a MBP3,1 on 14.04 with working Nvidia drivers.

The closest I came was [this guy](http://burningtyger.github.io/blog/2014/02/06/ubuntu-and-the-macbook-pro-3-dot-1/), but he doesn't state what version of Ubuntu he's using. I also tried 319, with no luck.

I have tried switching to GDM. With GDM, it will at least let me login via tty after halting after the following:

```
starting nvidia persistence daemon [fail]
```

Googling that didn't get me far, except that people say it's related to the driver (gee...).

I have tried installing very old legacy drivers (nvidia-173) but I could never get them to install as I guess they conflict with the newer version of Ubuntu – it would be unable to install dependencies via `apt-get` such as `xserver-xorg-core`, which wouldn't install because of dependencies for `libcheese-gtk23` and `libcheese7`.

EDIT/UPDATE:

As requested by David Foerster

- Xorg.0.log - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10686827/
- Driver install output (`sudo aptitude install nvidia-current`) - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10686824/
- kern.log of next boot - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10686826/
- `dkms status` from TTY after booting reports:

  - `nvidia-304, 304.125, 3.16-0-34-generic, x86_64: installed`
- `sudo dmesg` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10687090/

I was also able to install the `nvidia-173` drivers by running `sudo apt-get purge "lts-*utopic"` and then running `sudo apt-get install nvidia-173` (after doing a clean, -f and autoremove, update, upgr, etc) but during the install it would fail to compile for the kernel and upon rebooting I would get this in an error log:

```
(EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to load NVIDIA kernel module!
(EE) NVIDIA(0): *** Aborting ***
```

So I purged what was installed and followed David's guidance of posting logs while trying to install `nvidia-current`.

I hope this is helpful, I appreciate your attention.

EDIT/UPDATE:

It seems booting an old MBP through EFI with an nvidia card in ubuntu is a known thing that doesn't work, although I can't seem to find anything definitive that states why this is. Some people are suggesting booting in bios with a hybrid MBR. Guess I'm living without the nvidia card.

Comment: For the dependency issue of the legacy Nvidia drivers, I have this for you: [Can't install libglew-dev because libcheese and libclutter don't have the required versions](/q/588695/175814)

Comment: My best bet is, that the Nvidia driver writes something relevant to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. The output of `dkms status` may also help. For this the Nvidia driver needs to be installed of course (`*-current` should do the job). If possible, please install it from the command line and post the output of the package manager (and the DKMS script called during installation). If you don't know how to gather and upload log files from a terminal only, please refer to [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814).

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks - I have updated the post with new information.

Comment: Thanks. The installation log and DKMS status look inconspicuous, but `Xorg.0.log` clearly reports an unspecified error while loading the Nvidia kernel module and refers to the kernel log, which can be displayed with the command `sudo dmesg` (not `/var/log/kern.log` despite the name).

Comment: @DavidFoerster `sudo dmesg` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10687090/ - at [15.x] nvidia module fails

Comment: Actually that notification is [harmless](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-tainting-kernel-4175533442/#post5314496). Subsequently, in line 1017, the kernel reports the successful loading of the Nvidia kernel module. I'm out of ideas, if the driver still fails to work.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks, yes this has been quite annoying. I might fresh-install 12.04 and see if I have better luck unless somebody else jumps in here.